# Magento 2 - Where cart price rules applied in codebase?

Tags: magento2.2, shopping-cart-price-rules

I am working on magento 2.2.0. I have created some cart price rules with discount. I have added 5% product price discount in rule action. And 3 to 4 AND conditions for rule.

I want to know in magento 2.2.0 where these cart price rules are actually applied ? because with 4 conditions it's not working, working with only one condition.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Did you debug the location which I mentioned you?

Comment: Yes, I tried but no success!

Comment: No success means? This is the exact place where magneto apply shopping cart rules. You just need to debug your code by xdebug nothing else. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main class is responsible to validate shopping cart price rule is

[`\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Validator.php`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/SalesRule/Model/Validator.php#L27) , and I would suggest you to debug [process()](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/SalesRule/Model/Validator.php#L261) method and [canProcessRule()](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/SalesRule/Model/Utility.php#L83) from [\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Utility](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/SalesRule/Model/Utility.php#L16) class. you will surely get why your rule is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your new cart rules are all allowed to work in parallel in each other and not just stopping after the first rule is applied:

Go to: 
`Marketing -> Cart Price rules` and then click on each of the rules you wish to apply

ensure that `Discard subsequent rules` is set to "No"

Hope this helps.